# XCharter font with otfmath option does not set footnotes inside tcolorbox as superscript

Tags: footnotes, tcolorbox, xcharter

I have the following problem, which took me some time to drill down to a MWE.
The point seems to be that `tcolorbox` sets footnote marks in italic shape inside tcolorboxes.
When using `XCharter` as the math font, it results in the footnote marks not being set as superscript.

Look at the following MWE (I use LuaLaTeX to build them):

```
\documentclass{article}
% Geometry is just to get everything in a small area
\usepackage[paperheight=5cm,paperwidth=9cm,margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% FONT SETTINGS HERE

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  A\footnote{footnote} test! This \(\mathcal{D}\) should have a fancy swirl.
  Normal a, italic \emph{a}, math \(a\).
\end{tcolorbox}
A\footnote{footnote} outside works just fine as expected.
\end{document}
```

Having not additional font options gives this result:
[image]

With

```
\usepackage[otfmath]{XCharter}
```

or

```
\usepackage{xcharter-otf}
```

I obtain this result which has the correct math font but does not set the footnote marker as superscript:
[image]

With just

```
\usepackage{XCharter}
```

it works fine, but it obviously does not use the desired math font:
[image]

The following solution

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XCharter}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XCharter Math}
```

seems to work fine so far, but I'm wondering whether there is something missing, as the `XCharter` documentation suggests that using the first example should be the way to go.
[image]

Even though I have my solution with the last part, I'd like to understand where this issue comes from and whether this is expected behavior or possibly a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `xcharter-otf`, which is what you get when you call `XCharter` with the `otfmath` package, does

```
\RequirePackage{realscripts}
```

which works well with numbers, but not with letters in the italic font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{XCharter}

\begin{document}

t\textsuperscript{1234567890abcdefg}

t\textsuperscript{\itshape 1234567890abcdefg}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't see a way to disable loading `realscripts` other than resorting to a lower level construction.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Geometry is just to get everything in a small area
\usepackage[paperheight=5cm,paperwidth=9cm,margin=5mm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\disable@package@load{realscripts}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[otfmath]{XCharter}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% FONT SETTINGS HERE

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  A\footnote{footnote} test! This \(\mathcal{D}\) should have a fancy swirl.
  Normal a, italic \emph{a}, math \(a\).
\end{tcolorbox}
A\footnote{footnote} outside works just fine as expected.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, disable `\realsuperscript` in `\parbox` and `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Geometry is just to get everything in a small area
\usepackage[paperheight=5cm,paperwidth=9cm,margin=5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[otfmath]{XCharter}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\AddToHook{cmd/@parboxrestore/after}{%
  \RenewCommandCopy\realsuperscript\fakesuperscript
}

% FONT SETTINGS HERE

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  A\footnote{footnote} test! This \(\mathcal{D}\) should have a fancy swirl.
  Normal a, italic \emph{a}, math \(a\).
\end{tcolorbox}
A\footnote{footnote} outside works just fine as expected.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great and detailed answer (as always)!